# (SQL)Copy text after the last comma from one column to a new one

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I do not have mySQL, but i am using **DB Browser for SQLite** for the databse.

I am currently designing a database on properties in London and one of the column is address.
For Example, addresss column has: **[Ovanna Mews, 19A Buckingham Road, *N1*]**

Table name: West2

I want to move ***N1*** to a new column called **Postcode**.

The end product should look like this:

```
       address column: **Ovanna Mews, 19A Buckingham Road**
      postcode column: **N1**
```

Another example:

```
(old) Lowndes Square, Knightsbridge, London, SW1X
(new) address column: Lowndes Square, Knightsbridge, London      
     postcode column: SW1X
```

PS:My database has more than 100 columns inside, so changing it manually would not be considered

Comment: A word of caution; are you absolutely certain the last part will always be the postcode? If it's user input, they may well type :"Ovanna Mews, 19A Buckingham Road, N1, UNITED KINGDOM"  or more likely "Ovanna Mews, 19A Buckingham Road"

Comment: Is 'N1' the actual value you want to move, or just the last delimited value you are looking to move?

Comment: some of the entries does not have a post code but at least 90% of them does have a post code at the end. N1 is the actual post code i want to move.

Comment: This is difficult to do in SQLite as there is no split function. You can either switch to a different database like MySql and Oracle which provide a split function. If you cannot do this, your best bet is to write a code in java/python and modify the underlying text file and separate out the post code as a new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: [As you stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219340/sqlcopy-text-after-the-last-comma-from-one-column-to-a-new-one/45220197#comment77407877_45219965) you were able to edit it onto `google sheets` but doesn't know how to `import` it to the datebase, so I'll answer that. What you're looking for is `importing CSV file`.

EDIT2: Just correctly read that you also need to know how to `split the values at G. Spreadsheets`. This is a little complicated to explain, but easy to do...

First on `Google spreadsheet` select the whole address's column (by clicking at the Letter of the column). Go to the tab `Data > split text to columns...`. Since your column already have commas, it'll split everything between commas into columns.

```
| E            | F           | G            |  H    |
|:-------------|------------:|:------------:|:-----:|
|Lowndes Square|Knightsbridge|     London   |  SW1X |
```

Now you'll need to join the columns you need and add the comma, you can do this by using `&", "&` like this onto another column:

```
=E2&", "&F2&", "&G2
```

**Note** that there might be more than 4 columns, so unfortunately you'll need to adjust manually which columns to join.

Lastly for this part, you'll need to copy this new column as values only, simply `ctrl + c` it and paste it onto another column with `CTRL + SHIFT + V` (or `Edit tab > Paste Special > Paste values only`)

Then, you'll need to download your sheet from G.Sheets as CSV: `File > Download as > Comma-separated Values (CSV current spreadsheet)`. **Make sure that the order of the sheet's columns are the same as the SQL Table and, if the first line of this sheet are the names of the columns, delete the line**

I suggest to create another table for this (because if you don't clear it first, you'll have duplicate data = the ones before editing postcode and the ones after). Then, following [this post to import through SQLLite for browser](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/106201-how-to-use-sqlite-db-browser-to-import-inventory-from-csv-file), `File > Import > Table from .CSV file > SHEET_GENERATED_BY_GSHEETS.csv`, and select your table.

I'll leave my previous answer bellow in case anyone lands here from search engine.

---

If the `postcode` in the current `address` is **always at the end and always 2 characters long and preceded by a comma and space**, you can first update the values from `postcode` using `select address` combined with [substr](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/substr.php) and later `updating address` by removing the last 4 digits, combining [ltrim](http://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/core-functions-ltrim.php) and [substr](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/substr.php).

First part, does the table has an unique ID/primary key?

```
UPDATE a SET a.postcode = (select substr(b.address,-2,2) from table_name b where a.primarykey = b.primarykey)
FROM table_name a
```

Second part:

```
UPDATE a SET a.address = (select ltrim(b.address,substr(b.address,-4,4)) from table_name b where a.primarykey = b.primarykey)
FROM table_name a
```

Also, I advise you to copy the table with the all the data and test `updates` onto this new table, before trying on the real one. Either that or executing with a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before to execute `ROLLBACK` in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: thank you for your reply. the postcode always at the end, but it isnt always 2 characters long, some are 4 characters long|(i edited above already). I would say most o f them has a space and a comma but some does not have a postcode .

Comment: Edited my answer to comply your need to import from google sheets.

Comment: Just read that you need to first split the value on Gsheets, I'll add that to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I just followed as your requirement in MySQL

```
 create table West2(Address varchar(100), postcode varchar(100));
```

and `insert into West2(address) values ('Ovanna Mews, 19A Buckingham Road, N1');`

This query is executed and result as expected

```
    mysql> select * from West2;
+--------------------------------------+----------+
| Address                              | postcode |
+--------------------------------------+----------+
| Ovanna Mews, 19A Buckingham Road, N1 | NULL     |
+--------------------------------------+----------+
```

and as your question says about moving the last string after ',' to field `postcode` I've executed following command

```
update West2 set postcode=SUBSTRING_INDEX(Address, ',', -1), Address=replace(Address,concat(',',SUBSTRING_INDEX(Address, ',', -1)), '');
```

and the result got after executing query is

```
mysql> select * from West2;
+----------------------------------+----------+
| Address                          | postcode |
+----------------------------------+----------+
| Ovanna Mews, 19A Buckingham Road |  N1      |
+----------------------------------+----------+
```

Hope this helps, and might be same for SQLite DB

Note: This can alter all rows after first execution but if you execute again this query, this will result in removal of `,` from all the entries so please execute only once.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Unfortunately, I dont think SQLite supports the SUBSTRING_INDEX() function.. This is what coems out when i run tghe query: no such function: SUBSTRING_INDEX: update `test`
 set postcode=SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, ',', -1) AND address=replace(address,concat(',',SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, ',', -1)), '');

Comment: ok, just realise i can actually import it into google sheets to do it. i think google sheets has the split function but im not sure how to apply it...

Answer (score 0):

I got the working SQLite command to get the desired task, just need to execute three queries

[1]: `update West2 set postcode=(select replace(address, rtrim(address, replace(address, ',', '')), '') from West2);` -to update the postalcode column

[2]: `update West2 set address=(select rtrim(address, replace(address, ',', '')) from West2);` - to update the address column

[3]: `update West2 set address=(select replace(address, substr(address, -1), '') from West2);` - to remove the last `,` from all the entries
in address column

This will complete all the required tasks.

All the best :)